# Why matInput text field displays [object FocusEvent] instead of actual text where I used (blur) in Angular 8

Tags: angular

```js
  fetchContractNumber(contractNumber: any): void {
    this.changeField(contractNumber, 'vehicle.previousContractNumber');
    if (contractNumber) {
      this.s1 = this.facade.fetchContractNumber(this.equipmentModel.previousContractNumber).subscribe(data => {
        this.equipmentModel.previousWarrantyExpiryOdometer = data.data.contracts[0].expirationOdometer;
        this.equipmentModel.previousWarrantyExpiryDate = data.data.contracts[0].expirationDate;
        this.changeField(data.data.contracts[0].expirationOdometer, 'vehicle.previousWarrantyExpiryOdometer');
        this.changeField( data.data.contracts[0].expirationDate, 'vehicle.previousWarrantyExpiryDate');
      });
    }
  }
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="w-4/12 xl:w-4/12 pr-1">
            <input
              matInput
              (blur)="fetchContractNumber($event)"
              name="previousContractNumber"
              [ngModel]="equipmentModel.previousContractNumber"
              placeholder="{{ 'previouscontractnumber' | translate }}"
              type="text"
              #previousContractNumber="ngModel"
              [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher('vehicle.previousContractNumber', dealError)"
              [ngDave2EditableField]="dealIsLocked"
              editableFieldgroup="equipment"
              editableFieldCode="previousContractNumber"
              [editableDealStatus]="dealStatus"
            />
            <button
              mat-button
              *ngIf="equipmentModel.previousContractNumber && !dealIsLocked"
              matSuffix
              mat-icon-button
              aria-label="Clear"
              (click)="resetPreviousContractNumberFields()"
            >
              <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-error>
              {{ 'required' | translate }}
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your method it looks like you expect the $event passed from your event-binding of blur to be a contractNumber (so presumably a number), but it is not. You probably want $event.target.value